# Testing chained http Requests with concatMap() Angular7

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, angular7

I would like to simple test my *todo.service*-method:

```
create(listId: number, name: string): Observable<TodoItem[]> {
    const URL = `${this.apiUrlService.getApiUrl('list')}${listId}/Item`;

    return this.http.post(URL, { value: name }).pipe(concatMap(() => this.getAllTodoItemsByListId(listId)));
}
```

As you can see it is a chained http-call combined with concatMap();

I ended up trying a couple of things and this is my current state:

```
it('should create an todoItem', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockTodoItem = new TodoItem(1, 1, 'Test1');
    let postResponse: TodoItem[];

    todoItemService.create(1, 'NameOfList').subscribe((todoItems: TodoItem[]) => {
        postResponse = todoItems;
    });
    tick();
    httpMock
        .expectOne({
            url: `${apiUrlService.getApiUrl('list')}1/Item`,
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .flush(mockTodoItem);
    tick();
    expect(postResponse).toEqual([mockTodoItem]);

    httpMock.verify();
}));
```

My beforeEach():

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [TodoItemService, { provide: ApiUrlService, useClass: ApiUrlService }],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });

    todoItemService = TestBed.get(TodoItemService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    apiUrlService = TestBed.get(ApiUrlService);
});
```

I don't get it inside the subscription.
If the *create*-call looks like:

```
create(listId: number, name: string): Observable<TodoItem[]> {
    const URL = `${this.apiUrlService.getApiUrl('list')}${listId}/Item`;

    return this.http.post(URL, { value: name }));
}
```

just doing the POST request the subscription triggers. (But obviously not what i want)
So I get I have to mock the second GET Call somehow maybe too?!

the *.match()* Operator on the HttpClientTestingModule didn't really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mock a return of something from `getAllTodoItemsByListId`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
it('should create an todoItem', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockTodoItem = new TodoItem(1, 1, 'Test1');
    spyOn(todoItemService, 'getAllTodoItemsByListId').and.returnValue(of(mockTodoItem));
    let postResponse: TodoItem[];

    todoItemService.create(1, 'NameOfList').subscribe((todoItems: TodoItem[]) => {
        postResponse = todoItems;
    });
    tick();
    httpMock
        .expectOne({
            url: `${apiUrlService.getApiUrl('list')}1/Item`,
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .flush(mockTodoItem);
    tick();
    expect(postResponse).toEqual([mockTodoItem]);

    httpMock.verify();
}));
```

May also need this import if you don't already have it:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```